# Passing a bearer token in a 'Web Test' without Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, fiddler, azure-application-insights

I want to import a ".webtest" in Azure's Application Insights availability feature. I dont have a test edition of Visual Studio, but [this MSDN article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-monitor-web-app-availability/#multi-step-web-tests) suggests using Fiddler as another option to creating web tests.

I need to perform 2 requests on a REST API:

1. Request a bearer token from the `connect/token` endpoint.
2. Perform a GET at `api/resources` with the bearer token (retrieved from the above request) in the header.

It's a typical client credentials OAuth 2 flow.

I cannot seem to figure out how to do this with Fiddler. Basically I need to extract a value from the response body of request 1 and use it as the header value in request 2.

This is what the web test looks like without passing the token:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestCase Name="FiddlerGeneratedWebTest" Id="" Owner="" Description="" Priority="0" Enabled="True" CssProjectStructure="" CssIteration="" DeploymentItemsEditable="" CredentialUserName="" CredentialPassword="" PreAuthenticate="True" Proxy="" RequestCallbackClass="" TestCaseCallbackClass="">
  <Items>
    <Request Method="POST" Version="1.1" Url="https://example.com/connect/token" ThinkTime="8" Timeout="60" ParseDependentRequests="True" FollowRedirects="True" RecordResult="True" Cache="False" ResponseTimeGoal="0" Encoding="utf-8">
      <Headers>
        <Header Name="Content-Type" Value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
      </Headers>
      <FormPostHttpBody ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <FormPostParameter Name="client_id" Value="myclientid" UrlEncode="True" />
        <FormPostParameter Name="client_secret" Value="password123" UrlEncode="True" />
        <FormPostParameter Name="grant_type" Value="client_credentials" UrlEncode="True" />
        <FormPostParameter Name="scope" Value="myscopes" UrlEncode="True" />
      </FormPostHttpBody>
    </Request>
    <Request Method="GET" Version="1.1" Url="https://example.com/api/resources" ThinkTime="0" Timeout="60" ParseDependentRequests="True" FollowRedirects="True" RecordResult="True" Cache="False" ResponseTimeGoal="0" Encoding="utf-8">
      <Headers>
        <Header Name="Authorization" Value="Bearer {{token}}" />
      </Headers>
    </Request>
  </Items>
</TestCase>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this comes back as the following example you can use a regex extraction to get it.

`{"token_type":"Bearer","scope":"user_impersonation","expires_in":"3600 ... "access_token":"{{TOKEN}}", ...}`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestCase Name="FiddlerGeneratedWebTest" Id="" Owner="" Description="" Priority="0" Enabled="True" CssProjectStructure="" CssIteration="" DeploymentItemsEditable="" CredentialUserName="" CredentialPassword="" PreAuthenticate="True" Proxy="" RequestCallbackClass="" TestCaseCallbackClass="">
  <Items>
    <Request Method="POST" Version="1.1" Url="https://example.com/connect/token" ThinkTime="8" Timeout="60" ParseDependentRequests="True" FollowRedirects="True" RecordResult="True" Cache="False" ResponseTimeGoal="0" Encoding="utf-8">
      <ExtractionRules>
            <ExtractionRule Classname="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.Rules.ExtractRegularExpression, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" VariableName="token" DisplayName="Extract Regular Expression" Description="Extract text from the response matching a regular expression and place it into the test context.">
              <RuleParameters>
                <RuleParameter Name="RegularExpression" Value=".*&quot;access_token&quot;:&quot;([^&quot;]*)&quot;.*" />
                <RuleParameter Name="IgnoreCase" Value="True" />
                <RuleParameter Name="Required" Value="True" />
                <RuleParameter Name="Index" Value="0" />
                <RuleParameter Name="HtmlDecode" Value="True" />
                <RuleParameter Name="UseGroups" Value="True" />
              </RuleParameters>
            </ExtractionRule>
      </ExtractionRules>
      <Headers>
        <Header Name="Content-Type" Value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
      </Headers>
      <FormPostHttpBody ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <FormPostParameter Name="client_id" Value="myclientid" UrlEncode="True" />
        <FormPostParameter Name="client_secret" Value="password123" UrlEncode="True" />
        <FormPostParameter Name="grant_type" Value="client_credentials" UrlEncode="True" />
        <FormPostParameter Name="scope" Value="myscopes" UrlEncode="True" />
      </FormPostHttpBody>
    </Request>
    <Request Method="GET" Version="1.1" Url="https://example.com/api/resources" ThinkTime="0" Timeout="60" ParseDependentRequests="True" FollowRedirects="True" RecordResult="True" Cache="False" ResponseTimeGoal="0" Encoding="utf-8">
      <Headers>
        <Header Name="Authorization" Value="Bearer {{token}}" />
      </Headers>
    </Request>
  </Items>
</TestCase>
```

Comment: Works great. Is there any way to write such tests without a VS test edition? From what I can see, Fiddler cannot do much more than record and playback requests.

Answer (score 0):

To **compliment** [James Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4445931/james-davis-msft)'s answer, if you need to login to https://yourapp.com/auth/login by **posting the JSON**:

```
{
  user: 'youruser', 
  password: 'yourpassword'
}
```

first base64 encode the json:

```
> echo "{user: 'youruser', password: 'yourpassword'}" | base64
e3VzZXI6ICd5b3VydXNlcicsIHBhc3N3b3JkOiAneW91cnBhc3N3b3JkJ30K
```

Then pass this base64 value in a StringHttpBody tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebTest Name="login-healthcheck" Id="e91b6e1d-3fa0-475f-a18b-b694b463589c" Owner="" Priority="0" Enabled="True" CssProjectStructure="" CssIteration="" Timeout="0" WorkItemIds="" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010" Description="" CredentialUserName="" CredentialPassword="" PreAuthenticate="True" Proxy="default" StopOnError="False" RecordedResultFile="" ResultsLocale="">
  <Items>
    <Request Method="POST" Guid="ef9d1d00-5663-476a-a3cb-ccf49c4d2229" Version="1.1" Url="https://yourapp.com/auth/login" ThinkTime="8" Timeout="60" ParseDependentRequests="True" FollowRedirects="True" RecordResult="True" Cache="False" ResponseTimeGoal="0" Encoding="utf-8" ExpectedHttpStatusCode="0" ExpectedResponseUrl="" ReportingName="" IgnoreHttpStatusCode="False">
      <Headers>
        <Header Name="Content-Type" Value="application/json" />
      </Headers>
      <ExtractionRules>
        <ExtractionRule Classname="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.Rules.ExtractRegularExpression, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" VariableName="token" DisplayName="Extract Regular Expression" Description="Extract text from the response matching a regular expression and place it into the test context.">
          <RuleParameters>
            <RuleParameter Name="RegularExpression" Value=".*&quot;access_token&quot;:&quot;([^&quot;]*)&quot;.*" />
            <RuleParameter Name="IgnoreCase" Value="True" />
            <RuleParameter Name="Required" Value="True" />
            <RuleParameter Name="Index" Value="0" />
            <RuleParameter Name="HtmlDecode" Value="True" />
            <RuleParameter Name="UseGroups" Value="True" />
          </RuleParameters>
        </ExtractionRule>
      </ExtractionRules>
      <StringHttpBody ContentType="application/json" InsertByteOrderMark="False">e3VzZXI6ICd5b3VydXNlcicsIHBhc3N3b3JkOiAneW91cnBhc3N3b3JkJ30K</StringHttpBody>
    </Request>
    <Request Method="GET" Guid="d566422f-af74-47bf-90aa-0c66db6ef567" Version="1.1" Url="https://yourapp.com/api/v1/healthcheck" ThinkTime="0" Timeout="60" ParseDependentRequests="True" FollowRedirects="True" RecordResult="True" Cache="False" ResponseTimeGoal="0" Encoding="utf-8" ExpectedHttpStatusCode="0" ExpectedResponseUrl="" ReportingName="" IgnoreHttpStatusCode="False">
      <Headers>
        <Header Name="Authorization" Value="Bearer {{token}}" />
      </Headers>
    </Request>
  </Items>
</WebTest>
```

Worked for me on [Azure Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/monitor/) Availability checking